# Oracle - Round all the numeric values in all columns

Tags: oracle, rounding

this is my first question.

For the first time I need to ROUND ALL THE NUMERIC VALUES contained in an Oracle table.

I start from the classic "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ..." (I have 147 columns) and I would like to round all the decimals I find in my rows / columns.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have a look at the [ROUND](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/oracle-numeric-functions/oracle-round-function.php) function, it might help

Comment: Are all the columns of **number** data type? If not, you need to explain further. Can you have strings (in a `varchar2` column) that represent numbers, for example '232.04' - and do you need to round those too? Or just round the numbers in `NUMBER` columns?

Comment: By the way, if you just need to `select` the data, with the numbers rounded, to put on a report, all reporting tools have features that let you round the numbers ON THE REPORT without doing it in SQL first.

Comment: No @mathguy, I have strings, dates, etc. in my columns

Comment: So - are you going to answer my second question next? Which was: Do you only need to round true numbers (in NUMBER data type columns), or also "numbers" that may be stored in string columns, like the **string** `'232.04'`?

Comment: @mathguy ... just the NUMBERS. I don't want to touch dates, strings, etc

Comment: I suggest that you write a query similar to `SELECT ROUND(COL1, 2) AS COL1, ROUND(COL2, 2) AS COL2, ... ROUND(COL147, 2) AS COL147 FROM YOUR_TABLE`.

Comment: Hi @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica ... sorry, I can't do that. I start from a "SELECT * FROM xyz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your answers ...

finally, I made a loop for all my columns and I re-wrote the query: the user insert a "SELECT *" and I replace the "*" with all the columns name (and the ROUND on the numerics).

It is not the "fastest" solution but it works ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **dynamic query** as follows:

```
BEGIN
    FOR ALL_COLS IN (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME,
               COLUMN_NAME
          FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>' AND DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER'
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || TABLE_NAME
                       || ' SET ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' = ROUND(' || COLUMN_NAME || ') '
                       || ' WHERE ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' <> ROUND(' || COLUMN_NAME || ')';
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you Tejash, but I don't want to update my table ... with your method I would upgrade it, is it correct ?

Comment: @LukeTheMore - OK, so you don't want to `update` the existing data. So, then, when you say in your original question that "you need to round all the numeric values", what does that mean? Where will you put the rounded values? In a `SELECT` query perhaps? In a view? In a new table? Please explain what you need to do with the rounded values.

Comment: I would write a dynamic statement to update all columns in a single `update` statement. Updating one column at a time will take 147 times longer (more or less), if we must update 147 columns.

Comment: I add some other details: I'm building a C# app to create some Excel reports using Spire.XLS library. When I try to write the values like this > 32,29318046839245599191992060129087918583 < my app crash. That's the reason why I would like to round all the numbers in my query to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can build you query like the below

```
    SELECT 'SELECT '
           || Listagg(Decode(data_type, 'NUMBER', 'ROUND('
                                                  ||column_name
                                                  ||') '
                                                  || column_name,
                                        column_name), ',')
                within GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
           ||' FROM '
           ||'TABLE_NAME'
    FROM   user_tab_cols
    WHERE  table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```